# Web Audio API Stereo Volume Meter

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to create the most basic **stereo** volume meter for mic input but my right and left meters are showing the same readings regardless of which channel I am speaking into.

Here's my code in action:
https://codepen.io/9880780/pen/oNdwbLz

```
const meterR = document.getElementById("meterR");
const meterL = document.getElementById("meterL");
const startButtonEl = document.getElementById("startButton");
startButtonEl.onclick = async () => {
  startButtonEl.disabled = true;
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: false
  });
  const context = new AudioContext();
  const mediaStreamAudioSourceNode = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  const analyserL = context.createAnalyser();
  const analyserR = context.createAnalyser();
  var splitter = context.createChannelSplitter(2);
  mediaStreamAudioSourceNode.connect(splitter);
  splitter.connect(analyserL, 1);
  splitter.connect(analyserR, 0);
  const pcmDataR = new Float32Array(analyserR.fftSize);
  const pcmDataL = new Float32Array(analyserL.fftSize);
  const onFrame = () => {
    analyserR.getFloatTimeDomainData(pcmDataR);
    analyserL.getFloatTimeDomainData(pcmDataL);
    let sumR = 0.0;
    let sumL = 0.0;
    for (const amplitude of pcmDataR) {
      sumR += amplitude * amplitude;
    }
    for (const amplitude of pcmDataL) {
      sumL += amplitude * amplitude;
    }
    meterR.value = Math.sqrt(sumR / pcmDataR.length);
    meterL.value = Math.sqrt(sumL / pcmDataL.length);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
  };
  window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
};
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solved: You must disable echo cancellation for it to work. (Why?)

```
{ "echoCancellation": false, "googAutoGainControl": false, "googNoiseSuppression": false, "googHighpassFilter": false }
```

Comment: Yep!  Chrome doesn't support echo cancellation on stereo audio inputs.  Worse yet, echo cancellation is enabled by default, because the assumption was made that everybody just wants video conferencing.  There is a new algorithm coming that does support stereo echo cancellation, and I think there's even a Chrome flag now to enable it but I don't know if it's just in Canary or what.